# Angular e2e testing - Uncaught ReferenceError: inject is not defined

Tags: testing, angularjs

I'm brand new to Angular.  Trying to write my app TDD style.  What I'm trying to do is write a test for *it should display the number of clients*.  To get this test to pass initally (without the inject stuff), I simply add the markup to the HTML `<h1>Clients (3)</h1>`.

I want to further expand on this test case by adding checks for when there are 2 and 0 clients, but to do this I need to directly modify the scope inside the E2E test and I'm not sure how to do that.  I get the `inject is not defined` when I try, as below.

What's the proper way to test this?

**scenarios.js**

```
describe('myApp', function() {

  describe('Client list view', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser().navigateTo('/');
    });

    // PASSES
    it('should display a list of clients', function() {
      expect(repeater('.clients li').count()).toBe(3);
    });

    // !!! TEST FAILS !!!
    it('should display the number of clients', inject(function($scope) {
      expect(element('h1').text()).toEqual('Clients (3)');
    }));
  });
});
```

**controllers/client-list-controller.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('forecastingApp').controller('ClientListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clients = [
    'Joe J.',
    'Brad C.',
    'Some Dude'
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For right now, you can't. You can use `inject` in unit tests using Jasmine, but it is not for e2e tests.

Comment: then how can we inject any service if we need

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind showing your test html to us? I wanna know the script files sequence in your html.
Yes. Scenario runner must be run using http or https. 
Or you can run e2e in a separate html, the format likes this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>End2end Test Runner</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="../..">
<script src="app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js" ng-autotest></script>
<script src="test/e2e/scenarios.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Attention, you must refer this file "angular-scenario.js"